# postfix , dovecot imap/pop3

Tags: postfix, dovecot, imap

I have a mail server, postfix and dovecot. I started both as a service:

```
: ~ # /etc/init.d/postfix Start
[Ok] Starting postfix (via systemctl): postfix.service.
: ~ # /etc/init.d/dovecot Start
[Ok] Starting dovecot (via systemctl): dovecot.service.
```

But when tried to telnet can not send mail:

```
: ~ # Telnet 192.168.xx.xx 25
Trying 192.168.xx.xx ...
Connected to 192.168.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ns1.xx.xx.id ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo mail.xx.xx.id
250-ns1.xx.xx.id
250-Pipelining
250-SIZE 10.24 million
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
mail from: tes@xx.xx.id
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: admin@xx.xx.id
451 4.3.0 <admin@xx.xx.id>: Temporary lookup failure
```

When trying to telnet to IMAP/POP3:

```
: ~ # Telnet 192.168.xx.xx 143
Trying 192.168.xx.xx ...
Connected to 192.168.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
: ~ # Telnet 192.168.xx.xx 110
Trying 192.168.xx.xx ...
Connected to 192.168.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I check postfix:

```
: ~ # Postfix status
postfix / postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is running: PID: 1523

: ~ # Postfix check
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /usr/lib/postfix/./lib postfix-util.so.1
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /usr/lib/postfix/./lib postfix-tls.so.1
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /usr/lib/postfix/./lib postfix-master.so.1
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /usr/lib/postfix/./lib postfix-dns.so.1
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /usr/lib/postfix/./sbi n / lmtp
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /usr/lib/postfix/./lib postfix-global.so.1
postfix / postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: / usr / lib / postfix / sbin / ./lmtp
```

:~# postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = txx.xx.id, mail.xx.xx.id, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydomain = xx.xx.id
myhostname = ns1.xx.xx.id
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128, 192.168.11.53/24
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = xx.xx.id
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

:~# dovecot -n

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-34-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap imap pop3
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: Please add log excerpts (especially `/var/log/mail.log` and configuration details (`postconf -n`, `doveconf -n`).

Comment: Also add log excerpts please, they usually contain very important information for debugging issues. And better reply with a comment after editing, just editing a post does not notify those who commented on your question.